# What is a "trit"?

Tags: radare2, terminology

With Radare when I do `?`, I get a list of answers in the result,

```
[0x00400a04]> ? -0x120 + 0x110
hex     0xfffffffffffffff0
octal   01777777777777777777760
unit    17179869184.0G
segment fffff000:0ff0
int64   -16
string  "\xf0\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff"
binary  0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000
fvalue: -16.0
float:  nanf
double: nan
trits   0t11112220022122120101211020120210210211100
```

All of these I understand, except a `trit` -- the last one. What is this used for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trit

Answer (score 3):

It's simply the value of the expression shown in the base of `3`.

```
[0x100001200]> ? 3
hex     0x3
octal   03
unit    3
segment 0000:0003
int32   3
string  "\x03"
binary  0b00000011
fvalue: 3.0
float:  0.000000f
double: 0.000000
trits   0t10
```

The implementation of it is in the [unum.c](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/libr/util/unum.c#L497) file.

Trit is just an equivalent of bit in the base of `2`. Have a look at [ternary numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) on Wiki.

Comment: But is this used at all ever, or is it there for just novelty?

Comment: it's just for convenience. If you need the value in base 3 you have it there. Not sure if I've ever used it ;)

Comment: I think it's there more for amusement than functionality. Seeing it there is funny, if you're into that kind of humor :D

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is used for [binary-coded ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system#Binary-coded_ternary) stuff, or would be anyway if anyone ever used it.

You can find a library which this [may actually be used for here](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/ternary/libtern.shtml).

I think it's total novelty.